# Detecting user idle from computer

Tags: javascript, flash, air, web

Solution found thanks to @Trinh Hoang Nhu:

Credits to @stacker ( [Java Keyboard/Mouse activity (even outside of my app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490469/java-keyboard-mouse-activity-even-outside-of-my-app) ) http://ksquared.de/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/

Is there any way to detect keystrokes and/or mouse acitivity from javascript even if page is not active? I'd like to just detect if user is idle or not. I'm sure it is not possible in pure javascript, baut mybe some flash applications can do it and iteract with javascript?

Browser addon is also an option. Can browser(firefox) addon monitor keyboard and mouse when inactive?

Also i have no exprience with adobe air, maybe this could be also an option?

**NOTE! I want to detect all activity, enev if my page in in backround. Ex: If user is writing it notepad(not in my page), id'd like still know that user is active..**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456519/javascript-to-detect-inactive-or-away-user

Comment: No, they were for detecting if user is at their page. I want to detect if user is at computer.

Comment: Then i think you will need an java applet

Comment: I know that flash can interact with javascript. But does java?

Comment: Sure, java applet can interact with JS. Java applet have more power than Flash and it may handle thing like your request

Comment: Okay, you comment was helpful: found this: http://www.jotschi.de/?p=90. You canpost it as answer :)

Comment: Actually you may post this: http://ksquared.de/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/ It works for win7 to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments: Sure, java applet can interact with JS. Java applet have more power than Flash and it may handle thing like your request – Trinh Hoang Nhu

Eventallly found this: ksquared.de/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook

Answer (score 0):

yes your can detect keystrokes and/or mouse activity from JavaScript
try to look at this post 
may be this will help you

[How can I detect with JavaScript/jQuery if the user is currently active on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009260/how-can-i-detect-with-javascript-jquery-if-the-user-is-currently-active-on-the-p)

Comment: Yes, i know i can do that, i wat to detect if user it at computer, not spcificlly at my page